# Getting data from Dark Sky API using handlebars, issue with routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, weather-api

I have an issue regarding the script which helps me get the data from Dark Sky API.
I am developing the app in node.js using handlebars.

I am trying to get just some specific data from the forecast script, send it to `app.js` script which does the page routing and then to add it to `forecast.hbs` page. 
Unfortunately, I am really stuck on this.
I have attached the photo with the code.

[image]

What I want to do is to get just some specific weather data, so, later on, I can use them one by one in the HTML code.

I have somehow to add them in the callback(right side), then in the middle, where the forecast routing is, then I think I need to replace `forecastData` with something else like..more variables and add those in the rendering part?

For example, I would like to take the icon variable, which contains the code that I need to add in the hbs page.

I want to do some binding by replacing `Skycons.RAIN` with `Skycons.{{icon}}`, where the icon should be in the middle file, like `forecast: forecastData`.

If I'm using `{{forecast}}`, I can show all the data that is on the right side, more exactly the variable `weatherDetails`, which contains the other variables.

How can I take advantage of binding and use it for the icon, for example?

Can somebody give advice, please? 
I am really confused...

Kind regards, Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

Why don't add an additional parameter to the callback function and then add it to the handlebars data object? Then you should have access to it in the template.

Btw are you using nodemon with docker? I'm also stuck with a problem, where nodemon isn't updating the container when the files are changed.

Comment: Hi there! that's what I've done a few minutes ago and apparently it is working fine.  So basically, where I have the callback function in the forecast file(right side), i have added the variables that I need, then added them in the rendering part, add the binding in the hbs file and it is working fine.

Comment: About the nodemon, I am using it just like a dependency. I have installed it using npm install nodemon, then I have modified the package.json,  at the scripts part, added the  instead of content at start: command that I am usually using to start the server, a.k.a.: nodemon /src/app.js -e js,hbs and simply run npm run start and it starts the localhost

Comment: I am not really sure how to use Docker unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, also seems to me the correct way how you should do this. Another imrpovment don't use as first parameter the error handler, don't think that is is very common. I prefer here to set the parameter as an object, where the order of the passed data isn't important anymore.

Yep without docker it works smoothly. Guess i have to look tomorrow if I can find an solution for this.

Comment: Another reason why I want to do nodemon with Docker is because of the volumes (so images do not have to be stored somewhere on the file system)

Comment: Spend now a couple of hours to search for this problem and I think it's not possible to run a development environment with docker. So I have to run it with nodemon locally and will probably host my images etc. on AWS S3